# ЦПУ. MIPS. Знаковое расширение

Tags: cpu, mips

Читаю Харрис и Харрис "Цифровая схемотехника". Подскажите, как выполняется операция вида (на аппаратном уровне)

```
addi $sp, $sp, -4
```

т.е. 4 преобразуется к -4 (000 0100 to 1111 1011) с помощью знакового расширителя и затем прибавляется к $sp в АЛУ?

Comment: вообще компилятор, т.е. ассемблер сразу в инструкцию запишет -4, а не 4. Так что во время выполнения процессор просто произведет сложение, ему не надо ничего преобразовывать, константа задана к операции как есть

Comment: а что до знакового расширителя, так при любом сложении 32 битного регистра с 16 битной константой эту константу надо расширять до 32 бит и она всегда расширяется знаком